# Why is remember me not working in Symphony 3?

Tags: symfony, remember-me

I have in my server symfony 3.4 installed. The remember me cookie worked perfect since now and I don't know what happened. The only potential difference is that now I installed PUGXMultiUserBundle to use FOSUserBundle with two different types of user.

I have these lines in my configuration files:

security.yml

```
main:
  pattern: ^/
  form_login:
     login_path: fos_user_security_login
     check_path: fos_user_security_check
     provider: fos_userbundle
     csrf_token_generator: security.csrf.token_manager
     default_target_path: homepage
  remember_me:
     secret: "%secret%"
     lifetime: 31536000
     path: /
     domain: ~
     secure: true
```

And on my config.yml:

```
framework:
  session:
  # handler_id set to null will use default session handler from php.ini
  handler_id:  ~
  save_path:   "%kernel.root_dir%/../var/sessions/%kernel.environment%"
  # user can be inactive for 6h
  gc_maxlifetime: 21600
```

Also I detected when I clean production cache with command line I have to change the permissions of the folders to write in them properly. Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

About permission problem you should follow one of Symfony's ways that are here:
https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/setup/file_permissions.html

About remember_me problem I guess the bundle doesn't send the `_remember_me` field data to login check action.

Also if you want to always set REMEMBERME cookie for user you can set `always_remember_me` to `true` in `security.yml` as described in this page:
https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/security/remember_me.html

Comment: well, I did the first thing to try to solve the problem with the command and didn't worked at all.

The second thing is that i don't want to remember always. They have a checkbox at login form where they can select if they want to remember the session. The problem is the rememberme cookie is not working :/